# okhttp3 with Retrofit 2.0.0-beta4

Tags: android, retrofit, okhttp

I'm trying to get my network class to log incoming JSON, I'd like to use HttpLoggingInterceptor from OkHttp3. Problem is my Retrofit object wont take OkHttpClient from okhttp3. Please let me know if you know what I'm doing wrong.

Gradle

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:2.0.0-beta4'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.1.2'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:converter-jackson:2.0.0-beta2'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.0.1'
```

Retrofit and client setup

```
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor;
import retrofit.Retrofit;

HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(interceptor).build();

retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(URL).client(client).addConverterFactory(JacksonConverterFactory.create()).build();

API = retrofit.create(com.glasshouse.glasshouse.Network.API.class);
```

Android studio says Retrofit  needs okhttp.OkHttpClient not okhttp3.OkHttpClient but if use that one, I can't use the HttpLoggingInterceptor ...

Thanks for any answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah nevermind - for those facing similar issues, use retrofit2 not retrofit

(Need to import retrofit2.Retrofit not import retrofit.Retrofit )

Comment: This is not an answer for your own question.

Comment: @Shubham Yes it is. Need to `import retrofit2.Retrofit` not `import retrofit.Retrofit`

Comment: Maybe you should read formatting tips on SO as mentioned here - http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting .

Answer (score 1):

As a reference for others, you need to compile "com.squareup.retrofit2" and not "com.squareup.retrofit" in your gradle.

```
//old
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:2.0.0-beta4'

//new
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.0-beta4'
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using following configuration for retrofit and it works well.

Inside build.gradle:

```
      compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.0.1'
      compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:logging-interceptor:2.6.0'
      compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.4.1'
      compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.4.1'
      compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.4.1'
```

Retrofit Configuration:

```
    private WebServices getWebServices(String serverUrl) {
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
    client.interceptors().add(interceptor);
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(serverUrl)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .client(client)
            .build();
    webServices = retrofit.create(WebServices.class);
    return webServices;
}
```